# Where is Symfony's Kernel handle() function called?

Tags: php, symfony, httprequest

I am trying to understand how Symfony works, so I'm taking a look on its internals. In `app.php` I have something like this:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';  
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();    

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

What interests me is the `handle()` function. `AppKernel` extends `Kernel`, which implements `KernelInterface`. The `handle()` function is implemented in `Kernel` and not in `AppKernel`. AppKernel just registers the bundles and the config file(s). The function is as follows:

```
   public function handle(Request $request, $type = HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, $catch = true)
    {
        if (false === $this->booted) {
            $this->boot();
        }

        return $this->getHttpKernel()->handle($request, $type, $catch);
    }
```

That means that if I modify this function to do something, that should happen on any request. For instance, typing `exit;` at the beginning of the function should break the application. However, my application works like nothing happens. Am I looking at the wrong function or what is wrong?

I've also cleared the cache many times, and tried both `prod` and `dev` environment but without success.

**EDIT**

It seems that it has to do with the `bootstrap.php.cache` file. If I change it to`autoload.php` instead, it works. The problem is that with removing it I get:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel' not found in E:\svn\medapp\app\AppKernel.php on line 8
```

What's the issue here? How can I run an app that doesn't depend on the autoloader?

Comment: Are you loading the app/autoload.php file?  Maybe update your question with the exact $loader = line you are using.  Because it should work.

Comment: It was initially bootstrap.php.cache and I changed it to autoload.php. What is the difference and why isn't Kernel found even though it is included in AppKernel.php?

Comment: What you've changed?

Comment: Instead of $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache'; I have $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

Comment: remove the exit statement, clear the cache with `--no-warmup` option, add the `exit` statement and see what happens

Comment: Still same. I think classes are being loaded from Composer's cache, so the way to use them is to load from autoload.php. But I'm wondering how to include them without the help of Composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony uses the [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function to automatically load every class that is needed. It makes all the require_once rules unnecessary while only the classes are loaded that we need. I found this spl_autoload_register in bootstrap.php.cache so it seems that if you skip this file from loading that you also killed the autoloading process.

Comment: Symfony in fact doesn't use spl_autoload_register() (it relies on the Composer autoloader, which uses it). As some classes, like Kernel are always needed, they are included in the bootstrap.php.cache file. If you want to always use the autoloader, you should require `vendor/autoload.php` instead of `app/bootstrap.php.cache`. Anyway, this answer doesn't really answer the question and should be a comment instead.

Comment: Then why removing the autoloader results in the app not finding the Kernel class in AppKernel(which extends Kernel)? Because the namespace is included, it has use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel; Why can't it find it without the autoloader and how to make it find it without the autoloader? Or how to include it manually?